# How do make Spring access dropdown box values

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

How do make Spring access dropdown box values.

I am trying to make Spring MVC get the value of one of my dropdowns.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/view/dateRange.jsp at line 28

25: <tr>
26:     <td>
27:         <div align="right">Last Month Of Full Data:</div></td>
28:         <td><form:select path="Lst_mnt">
29:             <option value="1">January</option>
30:             <option value="2">February</option>
31:
```

All that I am doing its to get the value into Spring not build the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not using the `<form:select>` properly. You have two options:

- use a simple `<select>` tag with `<option>` tags inside, and give it a name the corresponds to the model object field (`Lst_mnt` in this case, but avoid that underscore)
- use `<form:select>` with a `Map` in which you can fill the keys and values for the select

Thus you will *show* the values. Then:

- If you want to get the selected value - it will be filled in the model object when the form is submitted, so you will have it in your controller method.
- If you want to manipulate them in the browser - use javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `td` that includes the form:select does your form work correctly?

Is Lst_mnt a property of the form backing bean?  Also is it an integer or string field?

Maybe you can post the whole form?