# Spring security: Redirect after successful authentication based on a drop-down value in the login form

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I'm not getting selected drop down values from front-end when i use 'commandName' attribute along with spring security, as the LoginModel fields (strLogintype,strUserType)become 'null' when i get it in controller.

But when i'm not using spring security, the same code works fine.I did tried the solution mentioned in [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143912/spring-mvc-form-not-returning-value-from-dropdown-list) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968046/how-do-make-spring-access-dropdown-box-values) but it didn't work in my case.

My login JSP code is like this:

```
                    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $type = $("select[id='userType']");
        $page = $("select[id='signInPage']");
        $("<option>Account Summary</option>").appendTo($page);
        $("<option>Basket Order</option>").appendTo($page);
        $("<option>Portfolio</option>").appendTo($page);
        $type.change(function() {
                    ...
        });
        });
        </script>                              
    <c:set var = "url" value = "/j_spring_security_check" />
    <form:form method="post" commandName="portalLogin" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}${url}" name="f">
    <form:select path ="strUserType" style="font-family: tahoma;font-style: normal;font-size: 11px;" id="userType">
                  <form:option value="retail" selected="selected">Retail</form:option>
                  <form:option value="admin">Admin</form:option>
    </form:select>
    <div class="left"><spring:message code="label.startIn" /></div>
    <form:select path="strLogintype" style="font-family: tahoma;font-style: normal;font-size: 11px;" id="signInPage" > </form:select>
```

My controller code is like this:

```
       @RequestMapping("/signIn")
    public ModelAndView onClickLogin(
    @ModelAttribute("portalLogin") LoginModel loginModel, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {

    strLoginPg = loginModel.getStrLogintype();
    if (strLoginPg != null && strLoginPg.equals("Basket Order")) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:BasketOrders.html");
    } else if (strLoginPg != null && strLoginPg.equals("Portfolio")) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:portfolio.html");
    } else if (strLoginPg != null && strLoginPg.equals("Account Summary")) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:accountSummary.html");
    } else if (strLoginPg != null && strLoginPg.equals("General Settings")) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:settings.html");
    } else{
                    return new ModelAndView("redirect:adminConfig.html");
            }}
```

[Update]: 
I tried two ways:

I created custom authenticationsuccesshandler.LoginController is same as it is.When i run the application i see that CustomSimpleURLAuthenticationSuccessHandler is fired, but here again i'm not getting the selected dropdown value from front-end in controller and instead it's null.Because of this i land up in a different page (adminConfig).

second way:

I reverted back to my earlier code.I just used @RequestParam attribute for 'onClickLogin' method of LoginController.

```
   @RequestMapping("/signIn")
public ModelAndView onClickLogin(
        @ModelAttribute("portalLogin") LoginModel loginModel, @RequestParam("strLogintype") String strtype, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {
```

jsp page:

```
   <form:select path="strLogintype" name="strLogintype" style="font-family: tahoma;font-style: normal;font-size: 11px;" id="strLogintype" >
```

But i get following error 'HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'strLogintype' is not present'. It also says 'The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect'. 
What is going wrong here? Also, does @RequestParam serve the purpose of getting 'selected' dropwdown values in jsp page.

How can i retain the selected dropdown value once control goes to spring security and when it makes call to controller?

Comment: i got redirected to the view adminConfig.html because strLoginPg was null.

Comment: should i be including the redirect logic inside onAuthenticationSuccess method of custom success handler as shown in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769654/how-to-get-redirected-to-a-method-at-login-logout-before-target-url-called-in-sp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672850/spring-security-not-hitting-default-target-url-after-successful-authtication with /signIn as value?

Comment: yes. In success handler, write following: setDefaultTargetUrl("/signIn?strLogintype=" + request.getParameter("strLogintype")); super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working after i added the following:

1. RequestContextListener in web.xml

   ```
          <listener>
          <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
          </listener>
   ```
2. CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter class

   ```
       public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends
   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
       @Override
   public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
       final String strLogintype = request.getParameter("strLogintype");
       request.getSession().setAttribute("strLogintype", strLogintype);
       return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response); 
   } 
   }
   ```
3. CustomSimpleURLAuthenticationSuccessHandler class

   ```
           public class CustomSimpleURLAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends
   SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
           public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
       Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

       final String strLogintype = request.getParameter("strLogintype");
       String session= (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("strLogintype");
       setDefaultTargetUrl("/signIn.html?strLoginPg=" + request.getParameter("strLogintype"));
       super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
   }
   }
   ```

I noticed that CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter class itself did the work of storing the additional parameter in session. I used CustomSimpleURLAuthenticationSuccessHandler to append that additional parameter (strLoginPg) with DefaultTargetUrl (/signIn.html),which i think could not have been done with any other attribute in context xml. Thanks.